# New contributor experience on unix & linux

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

Instead of insta-deleting my 1h effort, you could:

- just give me the vote and let me do the work of deleting my question and moving the answer over to the other question
- close and give me a chance to improve the question
- if you have the (moderator) power, move it over yourself

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558200/aws-ec2-sftp-access-with-root-permissions-winscp

[image: deleted question]

Answer (score 7):

I'm afraid mods cannot convert a question into an answer. Because you posted it as a question, the only choice I had was to delete. I couldn't close it since, beacuse it isn't a question at all, I don't see how you could possibly edit it to fix it. If you did, it would end up as a duplicate of the question you are trying to answer so, again, not useful to have around.

And that couldn't be upvoted: it wasn't a question. And even if it were upvoted, if you then deleted it to go and post it as an answer, you would lose the reputation from the upvote. You would only keep the reputation if it had a score >3 and was older than 60 days. But we can't really allow something that isn't a question to hang around *for 60 days* and get 3 upvotes.

Even if I had not deleted it, that would just have gotten you downvotes since it wasn't a question. So the choice was between deleting it directly, or waiting for the community to close it. While it waited, I can guarantee that it would be attracting a steady stream of downvotes. So by the time it was closed, and then automaticaly deleted by the system, you would have ended up with even less rep than you currently have. The post had already attracted a downvote by the time I deleted it (that vote wasn't mine).

So I realize you had the best of intentions, but I am afraid that post was really not helpful the way it was made.

Comment: I could have created the answer, and then deleted my question. You could have taken my material and put it as an answer on my behalf. You could have closed, and I would have converted into a question with self-answer. Even as duplicate it would have allowed me to get the rep to answer the original question and eventually delete the duplicate.

Comment: @RetoHöhener how would you have created the answer? Your question would just attract downvotes, no upvotes. It was only ever going to lose you rep, not gain you any. [cont]

Comment: I could have posted your answer as mine, yes, but would you really have wanted me to do that? I can do so if you like, I could post it as a community wiki (CW) and get no credit for it. Although, to be honest, the only new thing in your answer as far as I can tell is about how to configure a specific windows scp client. The question doesn't focus on winscp so I don't know how relevant that is. The rest of your points have already been made by other answers. But sure, if you want me to, I can post your answer as CW.

Comment: Finally, if you want to convert it into a question, go for it! My deleting it doesn't make that any harder to do. If you feel a self-answered question, one that will almost certainly be closed as a duplicate, is worth it, your call. I expect it will also be downvoted since you will knowingly be posting a dupe, but that's your call.

Comment: Honestly I was not expecting the downvote thing to happen, but I believe your experienced assessment. So if I change it to a question focusing on WinSCP, do you think it will not be closed as duplicate?

Comment: @RetoHöhener no, I think it will be closed as a duplicate :(. What I can do, actually, is remove the protection from the original question so you can go ahead and post your answer. The protection is basically to avoid non-answers like "wow! great answer" and "thanks" and that sort of thing. Your answer is clearly not that, so I have now unprotected the question. Please let me know when you have added your answer so I can protect it again.

Comment: Thank you, that is helpful. I will let you know.

Comment: I posted the answer.

Comment: @RetoHöhener great, thanks! I re-protected it now